# ¿Como hacer una consulta a partir de una metaconsulta mysql?

Tags: mysql

Supongamos que quiero obtener todas las tablas que tengan una columna que se llame **'nombre'**. Esto se puede lograr fácilmente haciendo uso del esquema **'information_schema'** que nos proporciona **mysql**. Sin embargo, supongamos que quiero listar todos los nombres de la columna 'nombre' de todas las tablas que tengan una columna que se llame así.

**¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?**

Comment: Eso requeriría de la construcción de una función. En un `SELECT` normal no pueden ponerse nombres de tabla variables.

Answer (score 1):

Intente una sentencia preparada, [14.5 SQL Syntax for Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html), como la siguiente:

```sql
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT(
      'SELECT `nombre`
       FROM ', `TABLE_SCHEMA`, '.', `TABLE_NAME`
    ) SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL '
  ) INTO @`qry`
FROM
  `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`
WHERE `COLUMN_NAME` = 'nombre';

PREPARE `stmt` FROM @`qry`;
EXECUTE `stmt`;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt`;
```

Cuide la variable de sistema del servidor [group_concat_max_len](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len), para evitar truncar el resultado.